# How to process String stream effectively?

Tags: java, string, performance, memory-management, garbage-collection

I've attended interview session  and I was asked about ways of optimization of such pseudo-code. It works under the load. It utilize 100% CPU and 100% Memory. After some discussion it was mentioned that it is because of GC.

```
public class MyString processor {
    ....
    public String process(InputStream inputStream) {
       String input = getString(inputStream);
       int position = input.length() / 2;
       return input.substring(0, position)
            + "some_constant_string_inside" + input.substring(position);
    }
}
```

As we can see here we create 2 strings during this call. and if this method is invoked 1000 times  then 2000 String will be created. So it is a reason of memory consumption which is a root cause of unstopable GC work.

We agreed that it is a bad idea to create so many Strings.

First step was reading char array from socket and then we can modify this array inserting some string in the bigining.  (Here I still have aт unanswered question how can we create char_array with size = char_array_size_from_socket + some_constant_space_for_sting_in_the_beginning - from my view there are 2 arrays will be created)

In the end we decided that it is better to have char array buffer per thread and store it in thread local to avoid race conditions and concurrent reads.

Do you have any other ideas? Could you please provide pseudocode for a such solution taking into account that string size is unknown value and could be different for each string

Comment: "First step was reading char array from socket". How do you know there's a socket involved? Also, bad interview question. Did you ask whether `inputStream` is buffered?

Comment: @Kayaman interviewer said it. InputStream  is my invention here.

Comment: Did you get the job?

Comment: @Kayaman decision will be on Monday

Comment: @Holger yes, sure - corrected typo. Thank you for your answer - will try to analyze your answer later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn’t create two `String` objects per invocation, but *four* `String` instances, due to the use of `substring`. Unless you’re using `javac` with a target of Java 9 or newer, there will also be a `StringBuilder` instance under the hood, to perform the string concatenation. With the common compiler implementations, it will not make any attempt to precalculate the size, but start with the default capacity. So when we assume the substrings to be rather large, the internal capacity will be insufficient at each `append` call, causing a reallocation of the underlying array, including another copy operation for all but the first `append` call.

The simplest approach to avoid this multiple copying of the same character contents, is to change the method to

```java
public String process(InputStream inputStream) {
    String input = getString(inputStream);
    int position = input.length() / 2;
    return new StringBuilder(input.length() + "some_constant_string_inside".length())
        .append(input, 0, position)
        .append("some_constant_string_inside")
        .append(input, position, input.length())
        .toString();
 }
```

This basically does the same as your original method, so it doesn’t require any changes to the surrounding code. Compared to the string concatenation, as compiled prior to JDK 9, it pre-sizes the `StringBuilder` and it avoids the creation of the two `substring`s. In the best case, the JVM’s optimizer will recognize this pattern and pass the `StringBuilder`’s internal array directly to the new `String`’s backing array without a defensive copy, as the `StringBuilder` provenly won’t be accessed after the string creation.

So this reduces the number of copying operations from five times to two times or even one time when the JIT optimization takes place. This does not account for the copying/ charset decoding operations taking place within the `getString` method so far. When using `javac` and JDK 9+, the new string concatenation may perform better than `StringBuilder`, but since this would still require the `substring` operations, the manual `StringBuilder` use may still win.

If changes to the the surrounding code are allowed, we would need more information about it, to know what we are comparing with and which changes are possible. E.g. for a lot of purposes, a `String` result isn’t actually needed, but a `CharSequence` would do. So if you change the return type of `process` to `CharSequence`, you can omit the final `toString()` call and return the `StringBuilder`. So you would not need the JIT to eliminate the final copying step.

```java
public CharSequence process(InputStream inputStream) {
    String input = getString(inputStream);
    int position = input.length() / 2;
    return new StringBuilder(input.length() + "some_constant_string_inside".length())
        .append(input, 0, position)
        .append("some_constant_string_inside")
        .append(input, position, input.length());
 }
```

Note that the `process` method is such a method where a `String` is not required but any `CharSequence` would do. So we can change the return type of `getString` to `CharSequence` and enable a wide range of optimization options, depending on the actual requirements.

```java
public CharSequence process(InputStream inputStream) {
    CharSequence input = getString(inputStream);
    int position = input.length() / 2;
    return new StringBuilder(input.length() + "some_constant_string_inside".length())
        .append(input, 0, position)
        .append("some_constant_string_inside")
        .append(input, position, input.length());
 }
```

With this change, you may read into a reusable `CharBuffer`, which conveniently implements `CharSequence` already. You can also deal with `char[]` array manually and [`wrap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/CharBuffer.html#wrap(char%5B%5D,int,int)) the result upon return.

Another option for certain character encodings is to read into a `byte[]` array instead, skipping the charset decoding that would happen when using `InputStreamReader`, followed by returning a custom `CharSequence` which wraps the array. This works if the character encoding has a direct mapping from bytes to characters or if you have sufficient knowledge about the content, e.g. when the encoding is supposed to be UTF-8, but the specific content is known to be completely within the ASCII range.

This would halve the amount of memory due to the use of `byte[]` instead of `char[]` but also eliminate the implied copying normally happening with charset decoding operations (as you need a source `ByteBuffer` and target `CharBuffer` existing at the same time).

The most recent version of [`Files.readString(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readString(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.charset.Charset)) does a similar optimization. In the best case, it will return a `String` encapsulating the same array into which the file was read. Of course, application code can not go that far.

In principle, you could change the `getString` method to return a mutable `CharSequence` implementation, so `process` can insert the constant and return that very instance, but mind that this precludes any reusing of the buffer and further, inserting in the middle still requires copying all characters after that position, i.e. half the string, to a new position. If the capacity is not sufficient to hold the string to insert, it would imply a copying of the entire contents into a new buffer anyway. So, the effect of this optimization is not as large as you might expect.

Comment: Could you please explain: "In principle, you could change the getString method to return a mutable CharSequence"
What if I store mutable CharSequence in ThreadLocal ?

Comment: “return a mutable CharSequence” meant “return an object, *the caller* can modify”. The answer’s example uses the char sequence as-if unmodifiable, creating a new result object. Which means, `getString` *can* use and reuse a mutable buffer object with a thread local. But if `getString` returned an object that the `process` method can modify and return to its own caller, its lifetime would depend on that caller, which we don’t know anything about. So we have to assume that it could keep the object and still use it by the time, `process` is called again. Which would rule out reusing the object.